# Traduire « escalate an issue »

Tags: traduction, anglais, expressions, vocabulaire

Comment est-ce que je traduirais l'expression « I have to escalate the issue to my manager » en français ?

Cela veut dire que la personne va rapporter le cas à son supérieur pour chercher une solution, mais je recherche un mot qui est plus proche de la connotation de « escalate », avec une connotation « d'élévation » vers un plus haut niveau. Est-ce qu'un tel mot existe en français ?

Comment: In the business world: faire monter ou remonter la question vers mon supérieure.

Comment: @Lambie "mon supérieur" or perhaps "ma supérieure".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparemment, le calque *escalader* ainsi que *remonter* (ou *faire remonter*) sont tous les deux en usage. Dans les deux cas, c'est un jargon professionnel qui n'a presque aucun lien avec la sémantique habituelle de ces verbes en français.

Personnellement (mais ce n'est pas mon domaine), j'aurais tendance à dire que j'ai *référé* ou *signalé* le problème à mon superviseur.

ETA: J'ajouterais que la nuance que Un francophone signale ci-dessous est pertinente et correspond en effet à deux sens différents du verbe anglais.

Comment: Je n'ai jamais entendu *escalader* dans ce contexte, et je ne vois vraiment pas comment on pourrait l'utiliser. Si c'est courant au Québec, tu pourrais donner un exemple d'utilisation ? *Faire remonter* est la seule des trois premières propositions qu'on entend en France (et ce n'est pas du jargon).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, c'est courant chez nous (mais je travaille dans une boite américaine et nous jargonnons beaucoup).  Il y a une nuance entre les deux pour moi, _faire remonter_ c'est avertir qu'il y a un problème sans spécialement demander une action au niveau supérieur, _escalader_ c'est demander que le niveau supérieur agisse.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Moi je n'ai jamais rencontré le terme, mais j'en vois une mention [ici](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1333728&p=11370353#post11370353) dans le contexte du gouvernement du Canada, d'où ma réponse.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Je confirme qu'escalader (un appel / un incident ouvert au support) fait partie du jargon couramment utilisé en France depuis au moins 20 ans dans le domaine du support apporté par des centres d'appel. Voir par exemple http://recherche.relationclientmag.fr/procedures-escalade-gestion-reclamations.html

Comment: J'ajouterais _rendre compte_ en synonyme de _faire remonter_.

Comment: faire remonter la question

Answer (score 3):

Une traduction possible peut être *"la **promotion** du problème vers un niveau supérieur"* ou encore *"L'**ascension** au niveau supérieur"*

Comment: ascension? Je ne pense pas: J'ai fait remonté la question ou le problème à mon patron ou chef etc.

Comment: @Lambie "J'ai fait remonter", pas "fait remonté"

Comment: Oui, une erreur typographique.

Answer (score 2):

Courant également dans la boîte où je travaille, en Suisse, et utilisé directement traduit de l'anglais soit "escalader un problème, une situation" avec effectivement l'idée qu'on ne fait pas que signaler au niveau supérieur, on demande une action de la hiérarchie.

Answer (score 2):

> Je vais (devoir) *transmettre* cette information à mon supérieur
>   immédiat, à mon directeur.
>  Je vais (devoir) *[demander](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23332)
>   l'intervention* de mon supérieur immédiat, de mon directeur.

On s'inspire d'une définition même de l'[*escalade*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8352540) (« Processus qui consiste à transmettre de l'information ou à demander l'intervention de ressources additionnelles dans divers scénarios de gestion. », *GDT*) où on nous apprend par ailleurs incidemment que l'escalade est *dirigée* (vers des cadres, d'autres spécialistes), qu'elle peut être *hiérarchique/verticale* ou *fonctionnelle/horizontale*. Par ailleurs, *[signaler](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/11146), aviser, communiquer avec, faire part de... à...*, sont aussi utiles quand on s'éloigne du cadre d'une procédure plus formelle. C'est que généralement, un employé salarié *relève de* l'autorité de quelqu'un d'autre et il est de la nature de la fonction que certaines situations fassent l'objet d'un signalement, d'un rapport etc. Si une procédure nécessite que l'employé demande l'intervention d'un tiers, ou qu'il avise spécifiquement son supérieur, il peut alors y avoir plusieurs escalades, de nature différente, et dirigées vers des personnes distinctes. On a eu le privilège de lire les autres réponses et commentaires et on estime personnellement que *faire remonter* est particulièrement inapte à rendre ces nuances, en plus d'être peu précis et inutilement métaphorique (on a pensé au *sous-marin*, au *cerf-volant*, au *yo-yo*).

L'emploi de l'escalade pour la *progression des moyens militaires mis en œuvre* ([*Larousse*](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/escalade/30927?q=escalade#30839), [*Termium*](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-eng.html?lang=eng&i=1&srchtxt=escalation&index=alt&codom2nd_wet=1#resultrecs)) de 1964 (*DHLF/Rey*), par influence de l'anglais américain, est un terme qui s'est aussi introduit dans le domaine social (voir [remarque au *TLFi*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/escalade), pour traduire *escalation* ; puis en extension dans un sens similaire à une montée plutôt fulgurante, par ex. des prix). Le sens de l'*escalade* comme processus n'est certainement pas incompatible avec cette dynamique de surenchère des moyens, mais ce n'est non plus une panacée.

D'autre part on est d'avis qu'en langue anglaise le verbe [*to escalate*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/escalate?s=t) n'a aucun lien avec le *rock climbing* (l'escalade/l'alpinisme), et que c'est assurément l'*échelle* qui s'y cache ; le verbe escalader avec un complément premier comme *problème/situation* dans le sens en question va à contre-courant des attentes qu'on a avec le verbe dans son emploi usuel en français (l'alpinisme, l'action de grimper, et non de faire grimper, l'objet inanimé) ; on le trouve donc moins compatible et moins bien intégré que le terme escalade en soi, même si on l'a souvent [aussi entendu](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/11145/traduire-escalate-an-issue#comment44858_11146). Au final on préfère les verbes usuels de la communication, avec la référence au terme *escalade* au besoin.

Answer (score -2):

La traduction est : « surmonter un problème ».

> Je dois surmonter mon problème avec mon patron.

Le mot que tu cherche est sûrement « surmonter » car on n'escalade pas un problème, on escalade un objet physique.

Ex:

> Je veux surmonter ma peur des serpents.
>   Je veux escalader une montagne .

Escalader = to climb.

Comment: Tu n'as pas du tout compris le sens de surmonter en français. "surmonter mon problème avec mon patron" serait la traduction de "to solve my problem with (the help of) my boss" or "to solve the problem I have with my boss". Either way, this phrase in French would require clarification or some context to be understood. It's not what OP asked.

Comment: surmonter is overcome something.